# How to get the newly created embedded document with Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a schema with embedded documents, the setup looks like this:

```
var Guests = new Schema({
  email: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
  time: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
});

var Devices = new Schema({
  user: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
  time: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
  name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
  guests: [Guests]
});
```

I create a new guest with the following code:

```
// Check if already invited
Device.findOne({ '_id': req.body.device_id, 'user': req.user.href, 'guests.email': req.body.guest_email }, function (err, guest) {

  // Check for error
  if (err) return handleError(err);

  // If already invited
  if (guest) {
    return res.status(402).send({code: 'already_invited', message: 'This guests is already invited.'});
  } else {
    // If not invited yet, lets create the new guest
    device.guests.push({
      "email": req.body.guest_email
    });

    // Save the new guest to device
    device.save(function (err) {
      if (err) res.status(400).send(err);

      // Get the saved guest ID, but how?

    });
  }
});
```

Everything works, but i don't know how to get the newly created embedded guest document. I especially need the ID, but i want the whole new guest in my response. Inside the `device.save` function, `device.guests` already has the ID of the newly created record, so i could loop through it and find it that way, but i'm wondering if theres an easier way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

```
 device.save(function (device, err) {
      if (err) res.status(400).send(err);

      // use device here. i.e res.status(200).json(device);

    });
```

Comment: Yes, i tried using device here, but this object return the whole device, not just the new guest i just added.

Comment: @passatgt try `device.guests[device.guests.length-1]._id` you can also do this right after device.guests.push();

Comment: @Will sorry...I don't know how stackoverflow's review works...could explain what "code only answers tend to" is?...what I mean was, in my example, if he needs the `guest._id` after `save`, he needs to use `device.guests[device.guests.length-1]._id`

Answer (score 0):

If you actually create a Guests entity with the new operator, the _id property will be populated. Try something like this:

```
var guest = new Guests({guest_email: "foo"});
device.guests.push(guest);
```